# Extracting some data diagonally (EXCEL)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was hoping you guys could help.

What I have, is a screenshot of a probability table (the probability of a man dying, at a certain age, at a certain year). Essentially, I have a column I need to populate (from ages 55 to 120) with their corresponding probabilites.

I notice that if I go from C55, D56, E57 etc, I can get the required probabilities I need (blue boxes). I am just not sure how to extract those values so I can put them into the colunm I need.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From the attachment, I need to extract all the blue box values at positions C55,D56,E57......... upto age 120

Comment: Welcome! This is not difficult. You just need the OFFSET() function and the ROW() function twice. Just tell me why you start from cell **C55**? Judging by the screenshot, the first cell should be **B54**

Comment: Hello! I didnt copy the entire table. But something like an example from above: B8, C9, D10, E11 ETC.

Answer (score 0):

To get a series of consecutive integers, you can use a construct like `ROW(A1:A120)` (if your version of Excel doesn't have the [**SEQUENCE() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90)).

The formula for extracting the diagonal from a matrix would be like to

`{=OFFSET(<$first cell address>;ROW(A1:A120)-1;ROW(A1:A120)-1)}`

or for your example

`{=OFFSET($C$55;ROW(A1:A120)-1;ROW(A1:A120)-1)}`

This is [**an array formula**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), you need to end it with input by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Comment: How would I adjust this, If I need to get this data from a seperate excel sheet?

Comment: I have tried this formula, but it seems to be giving me the values outside of those I would like. For instance, I start at C57, then I would like D58, E59, F60 etc in that pattern until the end.

Comment: Change only the first parameter OFFSET() - the address of the first cell in the diagonal. Don't touch the ROW() parameters - they are only needed for left-to-right and top-to-bottom movement, it will always be the same. Perhaps you mean that you do not see the desired values? Oh, just grab the formula cell by the bottom right corner and drag it down.

Comment: hmm. With C57 it gives me the corret starting value, but it does not give me the correct diagonal elements. It dosent give me D58, E59 etc. It seems to be going along 1, then down 2 and taking that element each time

Comment: Oh yes, you are right - I did not point out this nuance: the address of the first cell must be absolute. Otherwise, when stretching the formula, it will change to C58, C59, C60, and so on, and OFFSET () will be calculated relative to the erroneous cell.

Comment: it works! Many thanks mate.!

Comment: @user1727724 If this solution resolves your question, then please consider clicking on the Accept button.

Answer (score 0):

To get the diagonal data from your matrix, just use the following approach:

```
=INDEX(A1#,  SEQUENCE(8),  SEQUENCE(8))
```

This is not tailored to your actual addresses or to your desired range. It just demonstrates the simple collection of a diagonal from your matrix/data range.

You'd need to edit for actual addresses. Using whatever clevernesses one desired to make it as non-hard-coded as you wish to work toward. Accompanying that, one can be clever about how the sequences are built. For instance, they could be relative to the whole table and start, not with 1, but a starting value taken from your actual starting point in the table or they could address the table presented to `INDEX` to take a subset of the full range in which the upper left cell is the desired starting cell in the full range and so the sequences start at 1.

As mentioned by the other answerer, older Excel versions had their ways of building the sequences for rows and columns, the most widely useful being `ROW(1:HoweverMany)`. To make those amenable to "cleverness" automating the sequences, one usually used `INDIRECT` but that portion can be drawn from a helper table placed somewhere using `INDEX` or using functions like `COUNT` or `COUNTA` for either number in the `ROW` function.

But the simple collection of the diagonal (which need not be the main diagonal) can be done simply and without either `{CSE}` entry or volatile functions. (Though volatile functions are very seldom any issue for a computer manufactured after, say, 2010.)